# Google earth image appears flat and in the wrong location when georeferencing

Tags: georeferencing, google

I've been trying to add an image of my site which I got from Google Earth Pro.  But I can't seem to georeference it properly using the georeferencing tool in Predictor noise modelling software[image].

I've followed the georeferencing tutorials and tried a bunch of things to try to sort it out but I've run out of ideas.  I've input the coordinates that I got from Google Earth,  and have gone through all the steps exactly but the image appears in the wrong location (next to my site), a lot bigger than it should, and completely flat. You can even see when grabbing the image and seeing the preview in the georeferenced tool that it isn’t correct.  It actually doesn’t grab the exact screen shot that I have ready with google earth.   I’ve also confirmed the coordinates in google earth pro match with the dxf that I’m using in the model.  For some reason the georeference tool imports it completely flat and in the wrong location, (wrong coordinates).

Have  you come across this before?

Comment: Are you doing the georeferencing in the Predictor Software or another package? I am not familiar with this package, so cannot comment on how best to go about it. Might I suggest you try doing the referencing in Q-GIS? It is open source and there are a lot of tutorials out there explaining how to do it. I try and take 2 images. One with Placemarks and one without. Then converting the placemarks to shapefile I use these to georeference the image. I can post a detailed answer if you like?